# WCF PUB - SUB Pattern Config File Usage

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, publish-subscribe

**Overview of Project:**

---

I have A WCF service and 2 Desktop Applications (One Publisher, Second Subscriber).

The WCF service is hosted on Windows server 2008 R2 Std Edition, and the Publisher is on the same machine. The subscribers are on the client machines.

The WCF service uses net.tcp binding since it's on a Public IP and other binding have NAT issues.

The Subscriber creates a callback channel upon subscription, and the WCF service invokes the client method as shown in the code Excerpt below:

```
MethodInfo publishMethodInfo = type.GetMethod(MethodName);
object ClientResult;
ClientResult = publishMethodInfo.Invoke(subscriber.CallBackId, new object[] { SendDataVal });
```

The Send Event is Invoked by the publisher depending on the schedule.

**My Question**

---

Now that i have 3 configs (App.config for both Publisher, subscriber), and a web config file. Which Configuration does the ***publishMethodInfo.Invoke(subscriber.CallBackId, new object[] { SendDataVal });*** use?

1. Does it pick the Time out form the Subsribers App.config at the time of Callback Id creation?
2. Or Does it use the App.config time outs for the Publisher that Invoked the Send data Event?
3. Or Does it use the Web.config time outs of the WCF service, that is actually publishing the data?